# How to Deploy my laravel project on a subdomain hostgator

Tags: laravel, deployment, subdomain, cpanel

[How can i do this .. when deploying my laravel to subdomain it shows a index of if anyone can help me ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvJCW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Point the domain to the public folder in laravel. This should solve your issue.